# What does the lifecycle of an Azure VM look like in terms of state transitions?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

From what I can gather, the overall status of an Azure VM is composed of two parts: `provisioningState` and `powerState`.

For example, one can see statuses similar to the following during a VM boot:

```
  "statuses": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/creating",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "Creating"
    },
    {
      "code": "PowerState/stopped",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "VM stopped"
    }
  ]
```

which may later turn into

```
  "statuses": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/creating",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "Creating"
    },
    {
      "code": "PowerState/starting",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "VM starting"
    }
  ]
```

and so on.

Now, I've searched the online Azure documentation but nowhere have I been able to find a detailed account of the lifecycle of a VM. I would both like to know the range of possible values for the states and the possible state transitions. I would love to see something similar to [Amazon's instance lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html).

Any explanation or pointer to documentation would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows the full lifecycle: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/states-billing#power-states-and-billing

Either:

```
Creating > Starting > Running > Stopping > Stopped
```

Or

```
Creating > Starting > Running > Deallocating > Deallocated
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several statuses of Azure VM:
When you create a VM, the first status is **creating**.
After create a VM is complete, the default status is **running**.
When you use Azure portal to stop the VM, the status is **deallocating**, after the VM deallocating is complete, the status will change to **stopped**.
When you want to start the stopped VM, the status will change to **starting**, after the starting is complete, the status will change to running.
When you try to delete the VM, the status is **deleting**, after the deleting is complete, the status will change to **deleted**, we can’t list this status by PowerShell.
[image]
update: when you try to **restart** the VM, the status is starting.
Best Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your response, Jason! So, this is the status that you can (only?) view in portal.azure.com? I wonder if this status is some kind of mix of `powerState` and `provisioningState` as it appears to borrow states from both models.

Comment: By looking in the Java SDK I can see that [ProvisioningState](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/batch/ProvisioningState.html) can be one of `CANCELLED`, `CREATING`, `DELETING`, `FAILED`, `INVALID` and `SUCCEEDED`, whereas [PowerState](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/management/compute/PowerState.html) can be one of `DEALLOCATED`, `DEALLOCATING`, `RUNNING` and `STARTING`.

Comment: Furthermore, your example assumes that everything works. What state will be entered on failure to provision the VM, for instance.

Comment: Your concern is correct, although we can't login this VM, but the status of VM is still running, so we can use portal to see the screenshot. In the portal, we select the VM, and select the Boot diagnostics, then we can use the screedshot to check the status of the VM.